# "Люди воспринимают их как живые игрушки (или как живых игрушек)" — как правильно?

Tags: грамотная-речь, падежи, управление, одушевленность

Думаю, что правильно "люди воспринимают их как живых игрушек". Но вдруг возможны оба варианта?
Хотелось бы знать еще и конкретное правило.

Comment: Хм...Наверное, "падеж" - это я неправильно выразилась. Падеж-то тут один - винительный) Но тогда еще непонятнее..

Answer (score 2):

Окончания одушевлённых существительных множественного числа в винительном падеже такие же, как в родительном: *малышки - малышек* (В.п. и Р.п).

В Вашем случае *игрушки* становятся одушевлёнными предметами, поэтому в данном предложении (с учётом смысла) выбираем форму *игрушек*: *люди воспринимают их как живых игрушек*.

В предложениях, где данное слово используется как неодушевлённое существительное в обычном значении, в винительном падеже множественного числа употребляется форма *игрушки*. Вот пример из нацкорпуса: *"На них можно было увидеть замечательные **игрушки**: крохотные яркие сундучки с подарками, китайские фонарики, корзиночки, куколки, шары и многое-многое другое. [Н. Ю. Феоктистова. Новогородняя ёлка // «Первое сентября», 2003]"*

Answer (score 2):

1) Нет сомнения в том, что в сочетании  ***воспринимать как***  используется форма В.п. для неодушевленных существительных **и форма Р.п. для одушевленных существительных,** например:

Ему сорок три года, но все без исключения преподаватели и студенты **воспринимают его как** неординарного, но, тем не менее, очаровательного **ребенка**. [Нина Щербак, 2010]

2) Однако сочетание ***живые игрушки*** с точки зрения **грамматической одушевленности**  может восприниматься  по-разному: к определению "живые" подходит форма Р.п., а к игрушкам ― форма В.п. **Отсюда возможно колебание в выборе формы.**

Примеры:

Однако это промыслительство не следует понимать в смысле механической предетерминированности, превращающей мир в часовой механизм, а Божество в своевольного и капризного тирана, **создающего себе живые игрушки**. [С. Н. Булгаков. Свет невечерний (1916)]

Дети часто видят в них **живых игрушек** и мучают их не со зла, а по незнанию. Сейчас вы все превратитесь **в живые игрушки.**